# Rollup.js useContext null error when consuming storybook app

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, styled-components, storybook, rollupjs

I have created a React Storybook, used TailwindCSS, Styled-Components, Prop-Types and other external libs and want to build the storybook using rollup to be able to consume the components in any React app. After creating the build, I have installed the package using `npm install '../Forest'`, but when using a component from '@comp/forest', I get the errors
`react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:` and  `react.development.js:1618 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`.

Here is my `rollup.config.mjs`

```
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
// Enables transpilation into CommonJS (CJS) format
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
// Efficiently bundles third party dependencies we've installed and use in node_modules
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
// Transforms our Sass/Tailwind into CSS
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

import pkg from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' };
// import { createRequire } from 'node:module';
// const requireFile = createRequire(import.meta.url);
// const pkg = requireFile('./package.json');

const config = {
  input: './src/index.js',
  output: [
    // {
    //   file: pkg.module,
    //   format: 'esm',
    //   sourcemap: true,
    // },
    { file: pkg.main, format: 'cjs', sourcemap: true },
    { file: pkg.module, format: 'esm', sourcemap: true },
  ],
  watch: {
    chokidar: {
      useFsEvents: false,
    },
  },
  external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal({
      includeDependencies: true,
    }),
    resolve({
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      browser: true,
      dedupe: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    }),
    babel({
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      babelHelpers: 'bundled',
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      babelrc: false,
      // presets: [['es2015', { modules: false }], 'stage-1', 'react'],
      // plugins: ['external-helpers'],
      presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }],
        '@babel/preset-env',
      ],
    }),
    commonjs({
      include: ['node_modules/**'],
    }),
    postcss({
      config: {
        path: './postcss.config.js',
      },
      extensions: ['.css'],
      extract: true,
      minimize: true,
      modules: true,
      inject: {
        insertAt: 'top',
      },
      use: {
        sass: null,
        stylus: null,
        less: { javascriptEnabled: true },
      },
    }),
    terser(),
    image(),
    replace({
      preventAssignment: true,
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
    }),
  ],
};

export default config;
```

And here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "@comp/forest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Forest is a React component library built with TailwindCSS, Styled-Components and Storybook.",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "tailwindcss",
    "styled-components",
    "storybook"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@styled-icons/bootstrap": "^10.47.0",
    "@styled-icons/boxicons-regular": "^10.47.0",
    "@styled-icons/entypo": "^10.46.0",
    "@styled-icons/evaicons-solid": "^10.46.0",
    "@styled-icons/fa-solid": "^10.47.0",
    "@styled-icons/material": "^10.47.0",
    "@styled-icons/material-rounded": "^10.47.0",
    "@styled-icons/typicons": "^10.46.0",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.8.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-paginate": "^8.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "storybook": "^7.2.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "installWTO": "yarn install --network-timeout 100000",
    "start": "storybook dev -p 3000 -s public --no-open",
    "build": "storybook build -s public",
    "build-rollup": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c --watch",
    "start-react": "react-scripts start",
    "build-react": "react-scripts build",
    "test-react": "react-scripts test",
    "eject-react": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "styled-components": ">= 6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-image": "^3.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^5.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-mdx-gfm": "7.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-styling": "^1.3.5",
    "@storybook/addons": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/cli": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "7.2.1",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.0",
    "@storybook/theming": "^7.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0 || ^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-perfectionist": "^1.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.12",
    "postcss": "^8.4.27",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "rollup": "^3.27.2",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2"
  }
}
```

Also, if I use the rollup config by `rollup.config.js` it won't work, throwing the error `[!] SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel';`

Here is the `main.js` from `.storybook`, if needed

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../src/**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)',
  ],
  /** Expose public folder to storybook as static */
  staticDir: ['../public'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-styling',
      options: {
        // Check out https://github.com/storybookjs/addon-styling/blob/main/docs/api.md
        // For more details on this addon's options.
        postCss: {
          implementation: require.resolve('postcss'),
        },
      },
    },
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-docs',
      options: {
        configureJSX: true,
        babelOptions: {},
        sourceLoaderOptions: null,
        transcludeMarkdown: true,
        csfPluginOptions: null,
        mdxPluginOptions: {},
      },
    },
    '@storybook/addon-mdx-gfm',
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/react-webpack5',
    options: {},
  },
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.resolve.extensions.push('.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx');

    // SASS + Tailwdind CSS
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(s)(a|c)ss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            // We always need to apply postcss-loader before css-loader
            modules: {
              auto: /\.module\.scss$/,
              // true
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
            },
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          // required for tailwind
          options: {
            implementation: require('postcss'),
            // postcss 8
            postcssOptions: {
              config: path.resolve(__dirname, '../postcss.config.js'),
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    return config;
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: true,
    docsPage: true,
  },
};
```

What I also want to specify is, that I don't use `import React from 'react'` in any component anymore and solved the build error with `{runtime: 'automatic'}` in babel preset.

I have tried many rollup configs, but none of them solved the `useContext` error.